# Run git commands from outside the repository

Tags: git

I often need to run certain git commands (usually git log) on files in many different repositories. I would like a way for git to automatically run commands such as

```
git log --oneline /full/path/to/file/in/other/repo
```

in the following manner:

```
git -C /full/path/to/file/in/other log --oneline /full/path/to/file/in/other/repo
```

without having to type `-C /full/path/to/file/in/other` or changing directory manually. I would like git to infer from the full path what repository the file is in.

Comment: If the other repo (e.g. `.git` folder) resides in `/full/path/to/file/in/other`, your usage of the `-C` parameter appears to be correct. What problems are you running into with it?

Comment: The command works, I would like a way to not have to type `-C /full/path/to/file/in/other` whenever I happen to be in another repository.

Comment: Well you need to *somehow* tell Git which repository to use. Like a wrapper script or shell aliases or whatever. They’d have to be maintained though. I’m not sure what exactly you’re expecting?

Comment: I want git to infer the repository based on the file path. The file itself does reside in a repository, so in the same way git can lookup the repo from my working directory, it or a script can look up from the file's location. If the file is outside a repository, then git should still complain as it does now.

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways to tell git where the repository is:

1. The most common is to look in the working directory you are in. This may be an option in combination with other shell commands like `pushd` and `popd`
2. You can direct the git command using the `-C` parameter as you are already doing.
3. You can set the `GIT_DIR` environment variable (described [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables) as "the location of the .git folder")